# Django Forms: Attributes on Select Element not being applied?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I've got a Django Model Form that I am rendering in a modal window. It's displaying fine and I have no issues ***except for the styling of one of the dropdowns***.

I can add/remove classes to the other field in the form without issue - but the Select widget does not use the attrs I am giving it.

***My Issue:***

The select widget in the Django model form is not applying the correct classes

***My Attempts To Fix:***

- I've tried setting the attributes in the `__init__` method
- Setting them as they currently are (which is the [recommended method from
  documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields))
- Creating another model to extend the Select widget as found here on SO

***My Code:***

*forms.py*:

```
class EvaluationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form definition for Evaluation."""

    # THESE ATTRS LOAD FINE AND CLASSES APPLIED AS EXPECTED
    evaluation_date = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control test"}),
    )
    # THESE ATTRS ARE NOT BEING APPLIED TO THE SELECT WIDGET - NO CLASSES APPLIED
    evaluation_level = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=EvaluationLevel.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.Select(
            attrs={"class": "form-control something something-else"}
        ),
    )

    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for Evaluationform."""

        model = Evaluation
        fields = [
            "summative",
            "evaluation_type",
            "evaluation_level",
            "evaluation_date",
        ]
        widgets = {
            "summative": forms.HiddenInput(),
            "evaluation_type": forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

*template html that renders the form:*

```
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
    <ul>
        {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}

{% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
    {% if hidden_field.errors %}
        <ul>
            {% for error in hidden_field.errors %}
                <li>
                    (Hidden field {{ hidden_field.name }}) {{ error }}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}

    {{ hidden_field }}

{% endfor %}

{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <div id="{{field.auto_id}}FormGroup" class="form-group">

        <label class="form-label" for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>

        {{ field }}

        {% if field.help_text %}
            <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}

        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            This field is required.
            {% for error in field.errors %}

                {{ error }}

            {% endfor %}
        </div>

    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

*Relevant models:*

```
class Evaluation(CreateUpdateMixin, CreateUpdateUserMixin):
    """
    Model definition for Evaluation.
    """

    summative = models.ForeignKey(Summative, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    evaluation_type = models.ForeignKey(
        EvaluationType, on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    evaluation_level = models.ForeignKey(
        EvaluationLevel, on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    evaluation_date = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True
    )
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    employee_locked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin_locked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin_locked_by_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    objects = models.Manager()
    managers = EvaluationManager()

    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for Evaluation."""

        verbose_name = "Evaluation"
        verbose_name_plural = "Evaluations"
```

***My Question:***

How can I get the Select widget to properly apply the classes I want to it? I'm trying to add Bootstrap styling to the widget.

Comment: You're overriding the widget as a `HiddenInput` for the evaluation_level field in Meta.widgets

Comment: evaluation_type is a hidden input. the evaluation_level is what I'm trying to change.

Comment: So, there was a line in the `views.py` file where the previous dev had written: `        form.fields["evaluation_level"].widget.attrs["class"] = "form-select"` so that was overwriting the class. Everything above works as intended.